# STRIPE error: In order to use Checkout, you must set an account or business name at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account

Tags: stripe-payments

I have found this error message:

"In order to use Checkout, you must set an account or business name at [https://dashboard.stripe.com/account"](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account%22)

several times when developing stripe connect.
But my account and business name is set all right.

Comment: You need to set an account name at https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account

Answer (score 24):

I got this error when moving to Stripe's new implementation, which involves steps:

1. Add a checkout button to your webpage that sends your customer to a Stripe-hosted checkout page.
2. Create an order success page to show your customer after the payment.

It says to

> First, make sure that you have [set up an account name](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account) on the Stripe Dashboard.

Once I added a name to my (test) account, it all worked fine.

Comment: Exactly that was the issue. It was showing an error in the console all along. should have understood that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is the error message when you want to use the same account for sending and receiving too.

Try to use a different account for sending.

It is quite confusing how stripe handles multiplle account with one login. Was never able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error cause of i didn't setup https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account so,make sure you setup it .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exe8s.png)

Comment: Please attach some code

Comment: @Umer Waqas i added screen to my setting account . you don't need to change any thing in your code .